# Spring Security 3.2 and maximumSessions - logging out not updating SessionRegistry

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Problem scenario:**

I am trying to use Spring Security v3.2.3 with Java configuration to configure session management so that maximumSessions is set to 1 and maxSessionsPreventsLogin is set to true, e.g.

```
.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

This would mean that if someone is logged in and the same login is used again in a different browser, the original person logged in remains logged in and the second
person trying to log in is denied.

**Problem with code:**

I have tried to follow examples and hints from the Javadoc - but the main problem with my code is that when you run my example code (see below), you can log in once, then log out - but if you try to log in again, you are prevented because Spring Security has not recognised that you have logged out.

I traced this to the Spring class *SessionRegistryImpl* - when you log in, the method *registerNewSession* is called, but when you log out, the method *removeSessionInformation* is not called - leading to the inability to log in for a second time.

I know that the method *removeSessionInformation* is not being called because this is supposed to be triggered by a specific type of listener that is not set-up by default. To set this up - in your sub-class of *AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer* - you must override the method *enableHttpSessionEventPublisher* and return true. The Javadoc for this method states "This should be true, if session management has specified a maximum number of sessions". Doing this appears to make no difference and the Logout still does not trigger a call to the method *removeSessionInformation* in *SessionRegistryImpl*.

The only other thing I have tried with no success is adding the *@Order* annotation to various classes as suggested by the Caveat section of the Javadoc for the *AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer* class. This made no difference either.

Is there something missing or wrong with the code or an issue with Spring Security?

I am using Java 1.7.0_51 with Tomcat 7.0.53.

The following is the code I have used, the JPSs, and a pom.xml with the libs used. I have tried to cut down the example to its simplest form.

The example allows you to login, see a welcome page with a logout button, and click the logout button.

MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer class:

```
package com.test.config;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
  extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

MvcConfig  class:

```
package com.test.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer class:

```
package com.test.config;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import javax.servlet.Filter;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebSecurityConfig.class, MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
    }
}
```

WebConfig class:

```
package com.test.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.web.controller"})
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter setupPageCache() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setCacheSeconds(0);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig class:

```
package com.test.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()     
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")        
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
               .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

CommonController class:

```
package com.test.web.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class CommonController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {   
        return "login";
    }  
}
```

login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body id="loginPage">
        <div id="loginWrapper">
            <div id="loginForm">                            

                <noscript>
                    <div>                            
                    <spring:message code="login.javascript_disabled" text="JavaScript is not enabled on your browser." />
                    </div>                    
                   </noscript>    

                   <c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl"/>
                <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">       
                    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">        
                        <p>
                            Invalid username and password.
                        </p>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">       
                        <p>
                            You have logged out.
                        </p>
                    </c:if>
                    <p>
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>    
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>    
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden"                        
                        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>                  
</html>
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
        <form action="${logoutUrl}"
            method="post">
          <input type="submit" value="Log out"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.testing.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-simple</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test-simple</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <description>Test for single session.</description>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>mmtest</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                      <source>1.7</source>
                      <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: were you able to find solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by following configuration in **`WebSecurityConfig.java`**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;

.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());



@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
    return sessionRegistry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using the Spring Security (configuration was made with programming configuration - not XML).

I could login, but when I logged out, the `invalidateHttpSession()` didn't work. The session didn't get invalidated, because the corresponding method hadn't been called for some reason.

The problem fixed by removing a primitive authentication filter that I was using in the bootstrap. 
So, a declaration of filters with wrong order maybe can cause similar problems while playing with Spring Security.